# How to create a string-array in xml format easily?

Tags: android, arrays, xml, string

Say I have a long list like the following:

العربية

مصرى

Asturianu

Azərbaycanca

Žemaitėška

......

How can I convert it to a string-array in xml format?

```
<item>العربية</item>
<item>مصرى</item>
<item>Asturianu</item>
```

Comment: There are lots of example on line of doing this, using the standard DOM and SAX APIs, or less-standard APIs, or XML tools of various kinds. Which ones have you tried, and what aren't they doing for you? Note that there needs to be a single top-level element for this to be a well-formed Document, though what you show would be a legal Document Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually could not find anything with online search relating xml formats. but I finally came up with this solution.

I copy the list to excel and arrange the  in 3 cells and copy-paste to xml. Then and cut paste again all to a new single cell in excel. Replace all " "(single space without "" created for no reason) with ""(just blank without "")

It works, I hope I have not taken the time of too many people

Comment: See my answer @birdost :)